# Incorrect result with a sum of 2 decimal rounded numbers

Tags: java, math

My application needs to round the numbers to 2 decimal places.
I have a document with 4 fields: `x`, `y`, `z`, and `Amount`, for example. And:

```
Amount = x*y/z;
```

Here is my problem:

```
TotalAmount: x(100)*y(41.30)/z(1000) = 4.13.

SubAmount1: x(70)*y(41.30)/z(1000) = 2.89 [2.891 before rounding]

SubAmount2: x(10)*y(41.30)/z(1000) = 0.41 [0.413 before rounding]

SubAmount3: x(10)*y(41.30)/z(1000) = 0.41 [0.413 before rounding]

SubAmount4: x(10)*y(41.30)/z(1000) = 0.41 [0.413 before rounding]
```

Now sum of all `'SubAmounts'` is not equal to `'TotalAmount'`. Getting `0.01` difference because of rounding.

How can I fix this problem? Please share your suggestions.

NOTE :  Saving complete decimal places '2.891' will not work for me as we have existing data and some other calculations are dependent on the rounded value of 'Amount'.

Comment: What do you want to alter - the total or one of the amounts?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Making a sum function that handles rounding of subtotals?

Comment: *Saving complete decimal places '2.891' will not work for me* -> Then how do you expect it to give real results? Also floating point operations do have some rounding errors, so there are minimal chances of getting the actual result.

Comment: @RohitJain I feel that this was answered with: "NOTE : Saving complete decimal places '2.891' will not work for me as we have existing data and some other calculations are dependent on the rounded value of 'Amount'."

Comment: Either live with such a difference or save more digits in your results. There is no other way.

Comment: WHat does this have to do with Java?

Comment: What most POS terminals are going to do is define the TotalAmount as the sum of all the rounded SubAmounts.  E.g. `TotalAmount = 2.89+0.41+0.41+0.41` and NOT `(100*41.30)/1000`

Comment: You really should have a Currency class if you're dealing with money.  Floating point number calculations do have rounding errors.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=254

Answer (score 0):

You can store your full (not rounded) SubAmounts in variables (for example S1 will contain 2.891, S2 will be 0.413, S3 will be 0.413, S4 will be 0.413). 
To fill your document, just put as SubAmount1 the rounded value of S1, as SubAmount2 the rounded value of S2, as SubAmount3 the rounded value of S3 and as SubAmount4 the rounded value of S4. The value of TotalAmount is obtain by rounding the sum (S1+S2+S3+S4).
Wish it helps you.